# Play Framework 2.4.x - Overwrite default Actor System creation

Tags: akka, playframework-2.4

Play Framework 2.4.x uses application.conf as configuration and creates Actor System internally. Using DI we can get the actor system reference.

I have a requirement where we need to pass my own configuration other than application.conf to create Actor System.

How we can overwrite ActorSystem creation in Play Framework 2.4.x

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution, slightly different than what I was looking but it solves my problem.

Write a class extending  GuiceApplicationLoader override builder method. In the builder method change the configuration as per your requirement.

For information check at https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaDependencyInjection and look for "Extending the GuiceApplicationLoader"